# How to implement Macro-scale dyanmics simulation with adhesive and cohesive failure?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, adhesion

It's my first question here about physics.

I would like to ask about the macro-scale physics (the governing equation) needed to implement a dynamics simulator with adhesion and cohesion. Consider the starting example illustrated by the picture below: [image: The starting example illustration]

A harder object is suspended static under a ceiling by a thick goo of adhesive in which its physical properties are not uniformly distributed (there may be blobs and holes of condensed adhesive). There should be a distributed load over the interface between the harder object and the thick goo of adhesive that restricts the movement of the object. The objective is to find a simple expression that represent the distributed load at the object-adhesive interface.
I can also write static force and moment equations for the harder object thanks to its known geometry as well.

$$
\sum_i{F_{xi}}=0 
$$

$$
\sum_i{F_{yi}}+W=0
$$

$$
\sum_i{\vec r_i\times\vec F_i}=0
$$

My question are:

1. Are there any way to represent the adhesive distributed load using the least number of parameters and are "reasonable physically plausible"? (like the distributed load will only act against the imposed acceleration (e.g. gravity))
2. Is it possible to just consider the interfacial force not the material properties of adhesive and the harder object? (the external force to the object by the adhesive is the boundary condition of the internal force of the object, hence "cohesive failure" within adhesive when there is a failure within the adhesive; "adhesive failure" when the local interface cannot provide a sufficient adhesion force.